# Solve for $x$ in $(e^{1-0.5x}+e^{0.5x-1})-\frac{e^2+1}{e} = 1.5$

Tags: calculus

$(e^{1-0.5x}+e^{0.5x-1})-\frac{e^2+1}{e} = 1.5$

I did:

$$(e^{1-0.5x}+e^{0.5x-1})-\frac{e^2+1}{e} = 1.5 \Leftrightarrow \\ e^{1-0.5x} + e^{0.5x-1} = \frac{1.5e + e^2+1}{e} \Leftrightarrow  \\ \frac{e}{e^{0.5x}}+ \frac{e^{0.5x}}{e} = \frac{1.5e + e^2+1}{e} $$

Then I made $y = e^{0.5x}$

$$ \frac{e}{e^{0.5x}}+ \frac{e^{0.5x}}{e} = \frac{1.5e + e^2+1}{e} \Leftrightarrow  \\ \frac{e}{y}+ \frac{y}{e} = \frac{1.5e + e^2+1}{e} \Leftrightarrow \\ \frac{e^2+y^2}{ey} = \frac{1.5e + e^2+1}{e} \Leftrightarrow \\ e^2+y^2 = (\frac{1.5e + e^2+1}{e})\cdot ey \Leftrightarrow \\ e^2+y^2 = (1.5e + e^2+1)y \Leftrightarrow \\ e^2-(1.5e + e^2+1)y+ y^2  = 0$$

Then I solved the quadratic equation:

$$y = \frac{(1.5e + e^2+1) \pm \sqrt{(1.5e + e^2+1)^2-4(e^2)}}{2} \Leftrightarrow \\ y = \frac{33.887 \pm \sqrt{1148.356 - 29.556}}{2} \Leftrightarrow \\ y = \frac{33.887 + 33.45}{2} \lor y = \frac{33.887-33.45}{2} \Leftrightarrow \\ y = 33.6685 \lor y = .2185 \Leftrightarrow \\ \sqrt{e^x} = .2185 \lor \sqrt{e^x} = 33.6685 \Leftrightarrow \\ x = \ln(.2185^2) \lor x = \ln(33.6685^2) \Leftrightarrow \\ x = -1.5 \lor x = 7$$

And so $x = 7$, but my book says the solution is 5. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To be faster

put $X=e^{0.5x-1}$ and solve for $X$ the quadratic equation

$$X+\frac{1}{X}=....$$

Answer (score 2):

Up to the solution formula of the quadratic equation everything seems a lot convoluted but right. But for the numerical values I get
\begin{align}
1.5 e+e^2+1&=12.46647884161921..\\
(1.5 e+e^2+1)^2-4 (e^2)&=125.8568703128170..\\
(1.5 e+e^2+1)-\sqrt{(1.5 e+e^2+1)^2-4 (e^2)}&=1.247883995881315
\\
(1.5 e+e^2+1)+\sqrt{(1.5 e+e^2+1)^2-4 (e^2)}&=23.685073687357118
\\
2·\ln(0.5·1.247883995881315)&=-0.943395733902386
\\
2·\ln(0.5·23.685073687357118&=4.943395733902386
\end{align}

---

You should also be able to see the hyperbolic functions, here the cosine hyperbolicus as the even part of the exponential function, in your equation
$$
\cosh(0.5x-1)=\cosh(1)+\frac34=2.2930806348...
$$
so that your solution is
$$
x=2\pm 2\text{Arcosh}\Bigl(\cosh(1)+\frac34\Bigr)=2\pm 2·1.4716978669... 
\\
=\begin{cases}
~~~4.943395733...
\\-0.9433957339...
\end{cases} 
$$
so both of your solutions are wrong.

Comment: I don't know anything about hyperbolic functions yet, but I will look back into this when I do.